# django vanilla views create instance with imagefield using CreateView

Tags: django, image, forms

I am using django vanilla views (https://github.com/tomchristie/django-vanilla-views)
to edit a model object (the Model CreateView), this model has an imagefield.

but on create it does not seem to save the image, maybe because my not standard usage.

the are a few things:

- for the model ImageField I am using a upload_to function to save the image to a specific dir
- The create is done with some information not to be filled in by a user, so I Am using a dispatch to get the related object from the url
- before saving, in the form_valid function, I use form.save(commit=False) than do some things before saving it and afterwards save the object

the code:

the function used for the upload_to

```
def get_image_path_albumphoto(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('albums', slugify(str(instance.album)), filename)
```

the model (at least the significant fields):

```
class AlbumPhoto(models.Model):
    .... some fields ...
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path_albumphoto, blank=True, null=True)
```

the create view:

```
class AlbumPhotoCreate(CreateView):
    model = AlbumPhoto
    fields=('all the other fields except the album','image')

def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.album = get_object_or_none(Album, id=kwargs['album_id'])
    return super(AlbumPhotoCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)    

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['album'] = self.album
    return kwargs

def get_form(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
    initial={'some_field':'gets_initialized here'}
    kwargs['initial']=initial
    return  super(AlbumPhotoCreate, self).get_form(data,files, **kwargs)

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.album:
        return 'an url using the album id with %d' % self.album.id
    return reverse_lazy('albumphoto_list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.album=self.album
    obj.save()
    success_url= 'some url with the object id as %d' % obj.id
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

but the image is never saved using this code.... it works when using the django admin to add the object,,, so it's something in using this CreateView

**update**

I tried to reverse my code first include album in the fields, removed the dispatch and form_valid functions... no succes... finally the intialising removed... (get_form) no succes as well... and this is parctically the default usage of CreateView... so it's probably something in the upload_to function... (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this problem was more generic than this question was formed:

The vanilla update view was an extended version of the GenericModelView, so this problem was more generic, and not caused by the django vanilla view.

To upload a file using a form view, the form tag in the template should have:

the enctype="multipart/form-data"

e.g.:

```
<form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```